# Save state of radio buttons javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am building a multiple choice quiz with javascript and was wondering how I can save the state of the radio buttons .So when a user returns to the browser their chosen radio buttons will remain in place. Here is a link to what I am trying to do. http://jsbin.com/soyivu/1/edit?html,js,output

Here are the two most important functions from the script:

```
function checkAnswer(){
  choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
  if ($('input[name=choices]:checked').length > 0) {
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
      if(choices[i].checked){
        choice = choices[i].value;
      }
    }

    if(choice == allQuestions[pos]["correctAnswer"]){
      correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
  } else {
    alert("Select Something");
  }
}   

function renderQuestion(){
  test = _("test");
  if(pos >= allQuestions.length){
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+allQuestions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
    pos = 0;
    correct = 0;
    return false;
  }

  _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+allQuestions.length;
  question = allQuestions[pos]["question"];
  chA = allQuestions[pos]["choices"][0];
  chB = allQuestions[pos]["choices"][1];
  chC = allQuestions[pos]["choices"][2];
  test.innerHTML = "<h2>"+question+"</h2>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='0'> "+chA+"<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='1'> "+chB+"<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='2'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='goBack()'>Prev</button>";
  test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Next</button>";
}
```

Comment: Where is the `_` function defined?

Comment: Try localstorage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: The '_' function is defined at the top of the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) would be a good starting point for you as already suggested in the comments.

I looked at your code and from what I understand, you'll have a couple of questions with only 1 right answer for each of them. You can simply use an array to store the `checked` answers. Following code snippet could be incorporated:

```
 var UserAnswers = [];
 //In your code where you get a handle on the checked radio button, simply do
 choice = choices[i].value; //I'm assuming here is where you get the value
 UserAnswers.push(choice);

 //Once you do this for all the questions, just do
 localStorage["answers"] = JSON.stringify(UserAnswers);
```

`localStorage` only supports strings and therefore we use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`. To retrieve the answers and update your checkboxes appropriately, you could do something like:

```
var StoredAnswers = JSON.parse(localStorage["answers"]);
//StoredAnswers[0] and so on will have the answers stored for the questions
```

Hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I will answer my question and post what I did.

Comment: @GrzesSlania, I think  you should mark an answer as accepted and close this question so that others in a similar problem might also get help out of it.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps that I did to save the state of radio button choices in an array and call them when the user refreshed/returned to the the page.

I created two global variables.

```
var UserChoices = [];
var storedAnswers = JSON.parse(localStorage["answers"]);
```

One to store the radio button choices in an array and the other to parse the stored answers which are stringified in the function `checkAnswer()`

In the `checkAnswer()`the checked radio choices are pushed into the `UserChoices` variable. After they are stored in `localStorage["answers"] = JSON.stringify(UserChoices);`

Later when `renderQuestion()` is called the checked radio choices are taken from the `var storedAnswers` and created.

Here is the answer code through a JSbin link. http://jsbin.com/soyivu/4/edit 
At Js bin you will see what I did. The one problem with JS bin is that it won't show the output because of JSON.parse - I am not sure why. What you can do is paste the javascript and html code into your editor and see what I did to make it work. You also must have jQuery and call `$(document).ready(function(){
    renderQuestion();
});`
at the bottom of the script.