# Save last state of radio buttons in a simple web app. Do I need a database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I have a simple web page with three radio buttons that, once checked, thanks to onChange() function, the application does things.

Now, I need to save the last state of the three radio buttons. Basically, I need to know which was the latest checked radio button.

The application will be accessible from different browsers from only one person so, there aren't issue involving multiple people changing the status at the same time.

I've found this question here
[Save state of radio buttons javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574404/save-state-of-radio-buttons-javascript)
but, as soon as I need the data "in the cloud", I can't save it on memory browser or in local on the pc

Am I forced to use a database to store this only data or, am I missing something?

Comment: If the user is going to use it from different devices, yes, you need some kind of database.

Comment: You could just save the state to a text file on the server - but that's probably got even more pitfalls (e.g. file permissions) than just using a database.

Comment: You don't need a database necessarily (although it's often the best solution to this kind of situation) but you do need some sort of permanent storage on the server side. Might be a database, might be a file, might be another remote cloud storage service...doesn't really matter as long as it suits your overall requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution but, an existing MySQL database works fine.

It can be also used an existing table used to store only static parameter. In this way, you can read the data easily using a SELECT as below

```
SELECT ParamName FROM Param WHERE id = 54
```

The data we need is saved under ParamName and it's identified by its unique ID 54 inside Param table

Answer (score -1):

Use a serverside script (php,nodejs,python etc) to write to a json file. And use xhr (ajax) call to call the serverside script. 
Or use a simple nosql database.